# 2010: Display Jive blog title on a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, list, sharepoint-server, sync

I have a blog in Jive. I'd like to display the title of the posts in a news ticker on a SharePoint 2010 page.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that in a case of Jive site provide you a **Feed URL** for your blog posts, I think this feature is available where I got **Feed URL** for Jive site and add it to SharePoint page as shown below.

To can read your `Feed URL` in SharePoint you should add `RSS viewer web part` in your SharePoint page as the following:

- Edit your page > add a web part> at `content roll-up` > add `RSS viewer`.

[image]

- once the web part is added, you should click edit web part and provide your Feed URL  below RSS properties.

[image]

**OutPut**

[image]